# Summing amount attribute according to some entry in other attribute

Tags: sql, t-sql

please help. Suppose I've the following table
[image]

What I want is to sum amounts of each currency and count of each currency and put them in new columns. How should select statement look like? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Is this SQL Server?, if so, which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   Amount
  ,Currency
  ,(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TableName WHERE Currency = 'USD' GroupBy Currency) as USD_SUM
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE Currency = 'USD) as USD_Count
..... Repeat for other currencies

FROM TableName
```

Not the best way to do it but it solves the problem.

Comment: No problem, do you mind marking the response as a solution? It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you realy want so i just asume:

```
SELECT Curency, sum(Amount) as SumAmount, count(Amount) as CountAmount
From table
Group by Curency
```

But pls, next time try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: Yep it is too easy question, but I'm trying to select table with many other unnecessary attributes, and I did like you do, it returns error to include other columns into group by as well, and when I enter all other except sum columns into group by it does not make sense. That was the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: Ok, then please specify your problem, and update the question.